# ckeditor replace <?php

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, echo

I have a cms, with integrated CKeditor. The Ckeditor replace the `<?php with <!--?php`. I want to write php code in ckeditor `"<div><?php $prod=products($cat_id); ?>....</div>"` and store it to MySQL DB.. and at the viewer's page i want to output `echo {$page['code']}` where inside ['code'] is the php string i wrote above. I have used `str_replace('<!--?php', '<?php', $page['code']);` but it outputs it as hidden text.

Answer (score 3):

The raw angle brackets in `<?php ?>` will confuse HTML to think of it is an element tag. wrap it inside`htmlentities()` like so:

```
echo htmlentities($page['code']);
```

Comment: Won't work, i also write in Greek so i have a problem with htmlentities()..it outputs all the html code as text to the page

Comment: In that case use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()`. `htmlspecialchars()` only encodes:
`& (ampersand)`
`" (double quotes)`
`' (single quotes)`
`<> (less than and greater than symbols)` and leaves the rest as is.

Comment: And if you cannot use that because of encoding of all `<` and `>` symbols then do an `str_replace('<!--?php', '&lt;php', $page['code']);` and `str_replace('?>', '?&gt;', $page['code']);` this will encode only the `<?php ?>` symbols

Comment: see what it outputs with the htmlspecialchars and entities http://www.spoteam.gr/38_PROIONTA

Comment: SOLVED! I used a special name 'Panel.products' and replaced it on page with AJAX, and turned out perfectly!